# Smoothing jagged edges of an image

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, scikit-image

I would like to generate a skeleton out of an image. Since the edges that are generated using `skimage` from the original image isn't smooth, the resulting `skeleton` obtained from `binary` has disconnected edges with knots.

```
import skimage
from skimage import data,io,filters
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.filters import threshold_adaptive,threshold_mean
from skimage.morphology import binary_dilation
from skimage import feature
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize_3d

imgfile = "edit.jpg"
image = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = threshold_mean(image)
binary = image > thresh
edges = filters.sobel(binary)
dilate = feature.canny(binary,sigma=0)
skeleton = skeletonize_3d(binary)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=2, figsize=(8, 2))
ax = axes.ravel()

ax[0].imshow(binary, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax[0].set_title('binarize')

ax[1].imshow(edges, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax[1].set_title('edges')

ax[2].imshow(dilate, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax[2].set_title('dilates')

ax[3].imshow(skeleton, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax[3].set_title('skeleton')

for a in ax:
    a.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

I tried using `dilate` to smoothen the jagged edges. But the contours in the `skeleton` has two edges instead of a single edge that is desired.

I would like to ask for suggestions on how the edges can be smoothened to avoid knots and disconnected edges in the resulting `skeleton`.

[image: edit.jpg] Input image

[image: output] Output images

Edit:After using gaussian smoothing

```
binary = image > thresh
gaussian = skimage.filters.gaussian(binary)
skeleton = skeletonize_3d(gaussian)
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try to combine 'thresholding' with 'erode/erosion' ? Not firm in skimage but generally a erode after a thresholding should thin down the liens w/o need of sobel/canny - not sure if that is what skeletonize_3d does internally... repeated thresholds && smothing the thresholded  image with a gauss might help before doing the other steps.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I tried `gaussian = skimage.filters.gaussian(binary)` and `skeleton = skeletonize_3d(gaussian)`
 after `binary = image > thresh` .Now the knots in the `skeleton` has been removed.But the edge lines are not continuous.Could you please suggest how this can be improved?

Comment: You should theshold the `gaussian` variable in your edit before applying the skeletonization. Presumably the threshold should be lower than the one `skeletonize_3d` seems to use internally.

Answer (score 2):

This median filter should do the work on your binary image for the skeletonization.

```
import scipy
binary_smoothed = scipy.signal.medfilt (binary, 3)
```

For the borders, I will probably use this and play with the parameters as shown in the link below
https://claudiovz.github.io/scipy-lecture-notes-ES/advanced/image_processing/auto_examples/plot_canny.html:

```
from image_source_canny import canny
borders = canny (binary_smoothed, 3, 0.3, 0.2)
```